# javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo() perform differently on different environments

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using Jersey(2.23.2) for building my service, the service will be packaged into a war file and then be deployed onto Tomcat. But during the deployment, I found the code below perform differently.

```
response.getStatusInfo().equals(Status.OK)
```

*response: object of `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`*
*Status.OK: `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status.OK`*

On machines with tomcat 8 used, it returns true, but on a machine with tomcat 8.5, it returns false.

I researched for a while and found that `getStatusInfo` returns `StatusType` which is an interface and `Status` actually implements it. I think it happens due to implementation differences but can't get further. So I'm not very sure that the version of tomcat is the key factor.

Could anyone tell me what on earth causes this difference?
Thanks

BTW: I switched my code to `response.getStatusInfo().getStatusCode() == Status.OK.getStatusCode()` in order to force it to perform consistently.

Comment: You could also use response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()

Comment: @ravthiru Thanks for the tip, it seems to be more brief.